# Bitshifting std_logic_vector while keep precision and conversion to signed

Tags: bit-manipulation, vhdl, fpga, bit-shift, hdl

In VHDL I want to take a 14 bit input and append '00' on the end to give me a 16 bit number which is the 14 bit input multiplied by 4 and then put this into a 17 bit signed variable such that it is positive (the input is always positive). How should I go about this?

like this? `shiftedInput <= to_signed('0' & input & '00', 17);`

Or maybe like this? `shiftedInput <= to_signed(input sll 2, 17);`

Or this? `shiftedInput <= to_signed(input & '00', 17);`

Does it see that the std_logic_vector it's getting is 16 bit and the signed variable is 17 bit and therefore assume the most significant bit (the singing bit) is 0?

Or do I have to do this? `shiftedInput <= to_signed('0' & input sll 2, 17);`

e.g. If I read in the 14 bit number 17 as a std_logic_vector [i.e. `(00 0000 0001 0001)`] it should be converted to the signed number +68. [i.e. `(0 0000 0000 0100 0100)`]

Comment: What is the type of `input`? What errors do you encounter with your various attempts?

Comment: input is a std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)

Comment: 1st option gives: no function declarations for operator "&"
2nd option gives: no function declarations for operator "sll"
3rd option gives: prefix is neither a function name nor can it be sliced or indexed
4th option gives: no function declarations for operator "sll"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std_logic_vector` is *compatible* with the type `signed` of `numeric_std`. So, the type conversion function is `signed` (not `to_signed` that converts between integers and vectors):

```
shiftedInput <= signed('0' & input & "00");
```

should make it. Note the `"00"` instead of your `'00'`. Bit strings are double-quoted while bits are single-quoted.