# Why does Quartus throw an error at my if-statement?

Tags: vhdl

I'm learning VHDL at the moment.

This may be a dumb question, but what is the problem with this process?

> "Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at invent_a_chip.vhdl(132) near text "'";  >expecting "(", or an identifier, or  unary operator"
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at invent_a_chip.vhdl(134) near text "'";  >expecting "(", or an identifier, or  unary operator

```
signal count  , count_nxt   : unsigned(29 downto 0);

...

process(switch, count)
    begin
    if switch(17) = '1' then
        count <= '1000000000';
    else
        count <= '100000';
    end if;
end process;
```

Edit: Lines 132 and 134 are the lines with `count <= '1000000000';` and `count <= '100000';`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitshifting std\_logic\_vector while keep precision and conversion to signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066106/bitshifting-std-logic-vector-while-keep-precision-and-conversion-to-signed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count must get a value in double quotes (not single), and exactly with 30 bits (numbers), not less!